# Initialization order: An array with a separate pointer to that same array

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, initialization-order

I have a line of code that declares a static array of `char`, like so:

```
char buf[7];
```

I would like to traverse this array using a pointer, but `buf` itself obviously can't be incremented or decremented. My question is basically, **is this legal, or is this undefined behavior:**

```
// Does this guarantee ptr == buf?
char buf[7], *ptr = buf;

// ... because if not, then this could crash my program!
std::cout << *ptr << '\n';
```

This and similar examples compile and run just fine on my computer (WSL, gcc 9.3.0) with all optimization flags. In every test I've run, `buf == ptr`. But technically, would the compiler be allowed by the C++ standard to reorder these declarations so that ptr is initialized to some junk value?

I could obviously split this up into two lines and avoid any doubt, but I'm wondering if this one-line declaration is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this legal

Yes

> is this undefined behavior

No

> would the compiler be allowed by the C++ standard to reorder these declarations so that ptr is initialized to some junk value?

No, it initializes `ptr` with the `char*` that `buf` decays into. If a compiler would be allowed to initialize them in the other order, it would need to fail compiling, since it wouldn't have seen `buf` yet.

Compare with these:

OK:

```cpp
char buf[7];
char *ptr = buf;
```

Error:

```cpp
char *ptr = buf;
char buf[7];
```